# Persistent MySQL Query Results w/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to persist the query results using PHP so you can use it another call to the web server?

i know there is no way to persist a resource in php but looking for an alternative way to accomplish this:

i have a reporting server and some queries will take several seconds and return 10,000's of records (could be 10's of MB in size). i would like to be able to use the resource mysqli_stmt::data_seek to page through the results when the user requests a new page instead of requering each time and using limit & offsets

is there any technology that would allow me to do this?

some thoughts would be to put a php socket server inbetween request the query through the socket server which can keep the resource alive for say 5 minutes for additional page requests. if the resource is no longer available it will then run the query w/ a limit & offset

any ideas or other thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your query cannot be optimized? Did you put every necessary indexes?

Comment: yeah where talking 10's millions of rows and pivoting on any data combinition of 37 data points and over a timeseries. the queries are really fast but when getting into larger result sets people don't mind waiting 4 seconds for the report but then to have to wait 4 seconds for each page is a problem. At this point it might be a good idea for us to look at an BI solution like a OLAP server (mondrian comes to mind)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)

PHP has an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) for it.

Comment: i appreciate the memcache comment but caching the full data set will require to loop through the entire result set (instead of just a page) and store large chunks of data in the cache.

we have already played around with this and its too slow. in some cases we are talking about 10's of MB of data

Answer (score 1):

If you serialized your data you could use [APC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [Memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) to persist an object / array that contains your data.  Memcached would require that your server runs the actual memcached server along with having the memcached extension installed, while APC doesn't require anything special besides the extension.

Comment: 10's of 1000's of records serialized into APC? Is that feasible/efficient?

Comment: appreciate it but there is too much data to store to loop through all results, store in it cache, reread it from cache as we are talking 10's of MB at times

Comment: @webbiedave: Nobody asked about efficiency, just about if there was a way.  ;)

Comment: @jadent: Perhaps you might want to investigate building some sort of temp reporting table then?  Something flat and indexed however you need it to be?

Comment: @crontab: could work i guess if the they where memory tables and u create a cleanup script to either remove the tables or if storing all the data in 1 table to remove expired rows. not sure how fast that would be but its a interesting thought.

Comment: @jadent: It would basically be a stepping stone to a proper BI solution like you mentioned in a comment on your question.  Depending on what the trigger of the report is, perhaps you could set up a cron job to build and prune the temp tables.

Comment: @Crontab: perhaps i should look into building that one idea i put in my post. could do it in PHP or node.js. could be a cool little piece of tech to persist the query results and might not be that hard

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9244/discussion-between-jadent-and-crontab)

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into using PHP's [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php).

One bad thing about is that it only allows you to save strings so you would have to serialize your data. Not sure how that would impact the performance but at least you'd be writing to and reading from RAM, which is always fast.

Another drawback is that as with every memory operation you need to specify how many bytes you want to reserve in advance, it's not dynamic like Memcache.

You could probably initially reserve much more than you need (e.g. 20MB instead of 10MB) and store the size of the currently stored data in the first 8 or so bytes. E.g. if your data was 123456 bytes long you could store the serialized data as "00123456{serialized data}" and then read it by defining the offset:

```
$size = (int) shmop_read($shmid, 0, 8);
shmop_read($shmid, 8, $size);
```

Another thing to remember is it only works on Windows but it shouldn't be a problem if you have a decent server backend :)